# Why does an embedded vimeo video disappear within the jquery cycle plugin if it's already started playing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, vimeo

I am trying to use the jquery cycle plugin to display a number of embedded Vimeo videos in a slideshow that users can manually flick through. This is all working perfectly on all desktop browsers but for some reason on an ipad if you have started playing a video it disappears from the slide when you move away. You can see an example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/gPfg7/. Try clicking previous/next a few times before hitting play on any of the videos, it works fine on desktop and ipads. Now reload it and click play on the first video and then click next and then previous so you come back to the first slide. This works on the desktop but on the ipad the video has disappeared but the audio is still playing.

I tried a similar thing on YouTube to see if it was an iframe/video problem, this also doesn't work but instead of the slide becoming blank it seems to just display a black YouTube player with no content or controls (but the audio is still playing): http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/gPfg7/2/. I cannot for the life of me see why this is happening or find any reference to it elsewhere, if anyone could shed any light on why this might be happening then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a "non-answer" answer: Getting Vimeo videos to work with JavaScript/jQuery showing/hiding is a royal pain. Never mind getting events to work with their javascript API.

**RANT** Their documentation leaves a *lot* to be desired. Sometimes their own examples don't work, if they're even provided. In terms of interacting with JavaScript, YouTube is miles ahead of Vimeo, and performs much more reliably. **END RANT**

I don't know what browsers you are targeting, but also know that showing/hiding Vimeo videos with JavaScript results in some odd behavior in different browsers.

I've found what I needed to do to pull this off was a couple things:

- If IE is a concern, unfortunately, you will have to use the Flash embed method. Sorry iOS. Showing/hiding HTML5-embedded videos with JavaScript will result in random videos loading with a black box, and not the 'key frame'. It really is a one-or-the-other situation - so pick which matters more to you: IE or iOS. It sounds like you're going to have to live with IE users seeing random black boxes.
- If you are relying on the Vimeo JavaScript API to respond to certain events, showing/hiding them is also a bit odd to get it to work cross-browser. I tried the Cycle plugin myself, but it killed certain other events (like pausing a playing video when a user switches to another slide). What I ended up having to do was attach a class to the 'active' container that had the video in it. I then set the CSS to have the `<object>` positioned absolutely at -4000px (that is, way off the page). When a container became 'active', it's `<object>` became `position:static` to bring it back on the page. So, technically, the videos are never removed from the DOM, just repositioned.

Those two bullets sum up many hours of pain that I went through working with Vimeo videos. (YouTube was a snap, but the client insisted on Vimeo) There were many "WTF" and facepalm moments. I hope that I've saved you a little bit of time.

Comment: Unfortunately I have been through a similar hell as you trying to get a multitude of popup jquery cycle slideshows containing videos working (and pausing/unloading etc via the API when they're not the focus). I think i have actually (finally!) got most of it working (apart from controlling vids pre IE8 which I can just about live with), the only remaining problem is the disappearing videos on the ipad which is why it's driving me nuts as I thought i had cracked it! Do you have any ideas what might be causing these particular problems as they're not related to the API? Thanks so much:)

Comment: Arg- I'm sorry, I really don't. When I went through this, I erred on the side of IE, and had to forgo getting iOS to work. I would try the position: absolute trick - it simplifies what you're doing to the DOM. I'm guessing iOS's interpretation of the DOM doesn't jive with making Vimeo videos show/hide.

Comment: What i don't get is why starting to play the video makes it disappear, but if you haven't played it it doesn't disappear. Playing it shouldn't have any effect on it's position you wouldn't have thought but that's the crazy iOS world we live in :)

Comment: I think that my have to do with the fact that when you haven't played a video, you're actually looking at a static image (which is derived from the video). That could explain why it doesn't disappear when manipulated with Cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you don't go to crazy trying to test your code, Youtube has been touch and go for the last 24hrs, at least on iMacs.  That may or may not be related to your issue but I wouldn't use Youtube to test anything for a little while.

Comment: It's vimeo i'm having problems with unfortunately, i was just using youtube as a comparison :(